# Firefox specific media query for a small screen

Tags: css

I'm having trouble creating a media query for Firefox when the browser is minimized. I want to apply the following query when the screen size has a max-width of 767px.

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix()  {
  #inner-content {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

I've tried this but it didn't work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
  #header-outer-container {
    height: 50px !important;
  }

  #main-menu {
    top: 50px;
  }

  #inner-content {
    padding-top: 60px !important;
  }

  @-moz-document url-prefix()  {
    #inner-content {
      padding-top: 0px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone in the future, this worked:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()  {
  @media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
    #inner-content {
      padding-top: 0px !important;
    }
  }
}
```